# Problemas ao agrupar informações por meio das funções ifelse e case_when

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, if, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tentando agrupar as informações contidas em cada um dos estados brasileiros em regiões.
Inicialmente eu verifiquei a distribuição destas em cada estado por meio da função `table`.

Dados: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x7pD2yH-u3EZk5TB_bjKzkqyX3K1H-Tv/view?usp=sharing

```
table(Dados$Estado)
               ACRE             ALAGOAS 
                574                2184 
              AMAPÁ            AMAZONAS 
                728                2624 
              BAHIA               CEARÁ 
               9818                5694 
   DISTRITO FEDERAL      ESPÍRITO SANTO 
              17497                4289 
              GOIÁS            MARANHÃO 
               5896                2705 
        MATO GROSSO  MATO GROSSO DO SUL 
               2984                2683 
       MINAS GERAIS                PARÁ 
              20858                4714 
            PARAÍBA              PARANÁ 
               3428               10608 
         PERNAMBUCO               PIAUÍ 
               6599                1908 
     RIO DE JANEIRO RIO GRANDE DO NORTE 
              26787                2858 
  RIO GRANDE DO SUL            RONDÔNIA 
              11739                1665 
            RORAIMA      SANTA CATARINA 
                514                7246 
          SÃO PAULO             SERGIPE 
              51701                1693 
          TOCANTINS 
               1209
```

Para realizar o que pretendo, inicialmente tentei utilizando cadeias de `ifelse` como segue abaixo, no entanto, veja que ao realizar novamente a função `table` da variável criada chamada regiões, a qual contém as informações de cada estado agrupadas por regiões, essa não apresenta os valores de maneira correta, isto é, a contagem deveria ser maior já que estou agrupando cada estado na sua respectiva região. Eu tentei também por meio da função `case_when` do pacote `dplyr`, todavia, a problemática persiste.

```
Dados$Regioes <- ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("SÃO PAULO","MINAS GERAIS", "ESPÍRITO SANTO", "RIO DE JANEIRO"), "Sudeste",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("PARANÁ","SANTA CATARINA", "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"), "Sul",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("MATO GROSSO DO SUL", "MATO GROSSO", "GOIÁS","DISTRITO FEDERAL"), "Centro-Oeste",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("AMAZONAS", "ACRE", "RONDÔNIA","RORAIMA","PARÁ","TOCANTINS","AMAPÁ"), "Norte",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("BAHIA", "SERGIPE", "ALAGOAS","PERNAMBUCO","PARAÍBA","RIO GRANDE DO NORTE","CEARÁ","PIAUÍ","MARANHÃO"), "Nordeste",NA)))))
table(Dados$Regioes)
Centro-Oeste     Nordeste        Norte 
        7338         4052         1707 
     Sudeste          Sul 
       25786         9892
```

```
library(dplyr)
Dados$Regioes <- case_when(
Dados$Estado == c("SÃO PAULO","MINAS GERAIS", "ESPÍRITO SANTO", "RIO DE JANEIRO")~ "Sudeste",
Dados$Estado == c("PARANÁ","SANTA CATARINA", "RIO GRANDE DO SUL")~"Sul",
Dados$Estado == c("MATO GROSSO DO SUL", "MATO GROSSO", "GOIÁS","DISTRITO FEDERAL")~"Centro-Oeste",
Dados$Estado == c("AMAZONAS", "ACRE", "RONDÔNIA","RORAIMA","PARÁ","TOCANTINS","AMAPÁ")~ "Norte",
Dados$Estado == c("BAHIA", "SERGIPE", "ALAGOAS","PERNAMBUCO","PARAÍBA","RIO GRANDE DO NORTE","CEARÁ","PIAUÍ","MARANHÃO")~"Nordeste")
table(Dados$Regioes)
Centro-Oeste     Nordeste        Norte 
        7338         4052         1707 
     Sudeste          Sul 
       25786         9892
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis uma solução com o pacote `dplyr`.
Para tornar o código mais legível primeiro criam-se vetores com os estados de cada região. Depois, num *pipe*, o `case_when` atribui uma região a cada estado.

```
library(dplyr)

Sudeste <- c("SÃO PAULO","MINAS GERAIS", "ESPÍRITO SANTO", "RIO DE JANEIRO")
Sul <- c("PARANÁ","SANTA CATARINA", "RIO GRANDE DO SUL")
Centro_Oeste <- c("MATO GROSSO DO SUL", "MATO GROSSO", "GOIÁS","DISTRITO FEDERAL")
Norte <- c("AMAZONAS", "ACRE", "RONDÔNIA","RORAIMA","PARÁ","TOCANTINS","AMAPÁ")
Nordeste <- c("BAHIA", "SERGIPE", "ALAGOAS","PERNAMBUCO","PARAÍBA","RIO GRANDE DO NORTE","CEARÁ","PIAUÍ","MARANHÃO")

Dados <- Dados %>%
  mutate(
    Regioes = case_when(
      Estado %in% Sudeste ~ "Sudeste",
      Estado %in% Sul ~ "Sul",
      Estado %in% Centro_Oeste ~ "Centro-Oeste",
      Estado %in% Norte ~ "Norte",
      Estado %in% Nordeste ~ "Nordeste",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )

table(Dados$Regioes)
#
#Centro-Oeste     Nordeste        Norte      Sudeste          Sul 
#       29060        36887        12028       103635        29593
```

### Leitura dos dados

```
google_id <- "1x7pD2yH-u3EZk5TB_bjKzkqyX3K1H-Tv"
google_file <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", google_id)
destfile <- "estados_brasileiros.csv"
download.file(google_file, destfile)
Dados <- read.csv2(destfile, fileEncoding = "latin1")
```