# Utilizando o If no R num data frame onde a coluna é de string

Tags: r

Tenho um data_frame com duas coluna (UF e Município). Quero criar uma nova coluna de nome região através da coluna UF. Eu fiz o descrito abaixo, porém deu erro. Sou iniciante no R e gostaria de entender o meu erro. Podem me ajudar?

```
if populacao$UF == ("AM", "AP", "AC", "RR", "PA", "RO", "TO") {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Norte"
  
} else if populacao$UF == c("MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PE", "PB", "SE", "AL", "BA") {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Nordeste"
  
} else if populacao$UF == c("MT", "MS", "GO") {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Centro-Oeste"
  
} else ifpopulacao$UF == c("SP", "RJ", "ES", "MG"){
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Sudeste"
  
} else if populacao$UF == c("PR", "SC", "RS"){
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Sul"
  
} else {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "ERRO"
}
```

Comment: Por favor, coloque um `dput()` dos seus dados.

Comment: Como falei sou iniciante. Agradeço desde já sua colaboração. O que seria dput()?

Comment: A função `dput()` retorna um data.frame com os seus dados. Leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Veja também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/510311/problemas-ao-agrupar-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-por-meio-das-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-ifelse-e-case-when/510316#510316), apesar de a pergunta não ser exatamente a mesma.

Answer (score 2):

O erro está ocorrendo porque você não colocou parênteses após o `if` e `else if`.

O correto seria:

```
if (populacao$UF %in% ("AM", "AP", "AC", "RR", "PA", "RO", "TO")) {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Norte"
  
} else if (populacao$UF %in% c("MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PE", "PB", "SE", "AL", "BA")) {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Nordeste"
  
} else if (populacao$UF %in% c("MT", "MS", "GO")) {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Centro-Oeste"
  
} else if (populacao$UF %in% c("SP", "RJ", "ES", "MG")) {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Sudeste"
  
} else if (populacao$UF %in% c("PR", "SC", "RS")) {
  
  populacao$regiao <- "Sul"
  
}
```

Eu utilizei uma função diferente, a `ifelse`, ela tem uma estrutura simular a função `SE` do Excel: `ifelse(TESTE, RESULTADO SE SIM, RESULTADO SE NÃO)`. Utilizei também o pacote `dplyr`, para usar a função `mutate`, que faz alterações em colunas, mas não é obrigatório.

Código:

```
library(dplyr)

populacao <- data.frame(UF = c("AM", "AP", "AC", "RR", "PA", "RO", "TO", "MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", 
                               "PE", "PB", "SE", "AL", "BA", "MT", "MS", "GO", "SP", "RJ", "ES", 
                               "MG", "PR", "SC", "RS"),
                        regiao = NA)


mutate(populacao,
       regiao = ifelse(UF %in% c("AM", "AP", "AC", "RR", "PA", "RO", "TO"), "Norte", UF),
       regiao = ifelse(UF %in% c("MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PE", "PB", "SE", "AL", "BA"), "Nordeste", UF),
       regiao = ifelse(UF %in% c("MT", "MS", "GO"), "Centro-oeste", UF),
       regiao = ifelse(UF %in% c("SP", "RJ", "ES", "MG"), "Sudeste", UF),
       regiao = ifelse(UF %in% c("PR", "SC", "RS"), "Sul", UF))
```

Obs.: Eu utilizei o comparador `%in%` em vez de `==`, pois você está comparando com mais de uma observação.

Comment: Muito obrigada. Me ajudou e muito.

Comment: A seguir ao primeiro `%in%` falta a função `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Eis duas maneiras sem `if` ou `ifelse`, uma em R base e a outra com o pacote `dplyr`.

Primeiro, para tornar o código mais legível, criam-se vetores com os códigos de `UF`.

```
Sudeste <- c("SP", "RJ", "ES", "MG")
Sul <- c("PR", "SC", "RS")
Centro_Oeste <- c("MT", "MS", "GO")
Norte <- c("AM", "AP", "AC", "RR", "PA", "RO", "TO")
Nordeste <- c("MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PE", "PB", "SE", "AL", "BA")
```

### R base

Depois de criar a nova coluna com `NA`'s, atribuem-se os valores com um índice lógico.

```
populacao$regiao <- NA_character_
populacao$regiao[populacao$UF %in% Sudeste] <- "Sudeste"
populacao$regiao[populacao$UF %in% Sul] <- "Sul"
populacao$regiao[populacao$UF %in% Centro_Oeste] <- "Centro-Oeste"
populacao$regiao[populacao$UF %in% Norte] <- "Norte"
populacao$regiao[populacao$UF %in% Nordeste] <- "Nordeste"
```

### Pacote `dplyr`

Esta solução é um pipe de `mutate` e `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)

populacao <- populacao %>%
  mutate(
    regiao = case_when(
      UF %in% Sudeste ~ "Sudeste",
      UF %in% Sul ~ "Sul",
      UF %in% Centro_Oeste ~ "Centro-Oeste",
      UF %in% Norte ~ "Norte",
      UF %in% Nordeste ~ "Nordeste",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

Comment: Obrigada pela colaboração.